# Does 31 necessarily imply the end of the month in a cron job?

Tags: cron

For cron job we know we can set time as below.

```
# +------------ Minute (0 - 59)
# | +---------- Hour (0 - 23)
# | | +-------- Day of the Month (1 - 31)
# | | | +------ Month (1 - 12)
# | | | | +---- Day of the Week (0 - 7) (Sunday is 0 or 7)
# | | | | |
# * * * * * command
```

What I want to know is that when we set day of the month 31, does this means the end of each month though the month does not  have day 31.

Answer (score 25):

No, 31 means 31.

However, you can do some trickery. Set the job to run on any day which could potentially be the last day of the month (ie 28-31 in the day-of-month field), and then replace your command with a shell expression comprising a test on the date guarding the command:

```
0 0 28-31 * * [ "`date +%m`" != "`date --date=tomorrow +%m`" ] && command
```

The expression inside the test brackets just asks if the month number today is different to the month number tomorrow, which of course will only be true on the last day of the month. Note that the form of this expression depends on your local `date` - you may need to tweak it if you don't have the current GNU version.

I should say that I didn't invent this - I found it with a quick Google in a mailing list post by a Matthew Jarvis. I would imagine this is very much a standard old Unix wizard's trick, though.

Comment: It can't be too old of a trick given the GNU-specific options to "date" =)

Comment: On stackexchange sites, asking a question which can be answered with a Google search, is NOT a bad thing. In fact it is a good thing, as the next person who will search this in Google will find the answer on stackexchange and come here.

Answer (score 17):

No, I think the best you can do is run at midnight on the 1st of the month, or set up individual crontab lines for each month (or at least, a line for months with 28,29,30 and 31 days)

```
0 0 28,29 2               * /my/command
0 0 30    4,6,9,11        * /my/command
0 0 31    1,3,5,7,8,10,12 * /my/command
```

Comment: Thanks Paul! I will follow the second one. For second method do i need to set the same file for three times right? Thanks again :)

Comment: Yes, you will need to repeat it.

Comment: I have no experience with cron, but wouldn't "0 0 28,29 2" execute twice in a leap year? Not that this would be a problem for the next two years, but still...

Comment: That's a good point, no easy way around that

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you can do this easily in the `crontab`.

One option would be to set `cron` to run the script every day and then make the script itself check if it is the last day of the month.

Answer (score 4):

I guess some implementations of cron have [a special character 'L'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#Non-standard_characters) meant for this purpose:

```
*    *    L    *    *    your_script.sh
```

would execute your script on the last day of every month

On the other hand,

```
*    *    0    *    *    your_script.sh
```

You can even specify something like:

```
*    *    *    *    1,5L    your_scrript.sh
```

to run the script on the last Monday and Friday of each month

or

```
*    *    *    *    1    your_script.sh
```

to run the script every Monday at midnight.

Answer (score 1):

This will do the job:

```
if [ $( date +%-d --date="tomorrow" ) -eq 1 ]
then echo Last day of the current month
else echo Not yet!
     exit 0
fi

exit 1
```