# cron expression to run a job on last working day of the month

Tags: cron

I need to schedule a cron job to run on the "last working day" of the month. Please can someone advise me on how to achieve that?

thanks 
Nick

Comment: any advice would be very much appreciated...

Comment: Month and day are well defined, but you do need to specify what you mean by "working day".

Comment: Hi, by that I mean I need a process to run a process at end of the month as in the last weekday (exc Sat & Sun). So if the last day is 31st (Sun), 29th (Friday) would be the last working day.

Comment: I've created a below script and i dont know if this is the right approach. Please can you experts help me to get this to work if this is thre only best way to achieve what im after?
`#!/usr/bin/bash
typeset -i x1_day_of_month=`date +"%d"`
typeset -i x1_month_of_year=`date +"%b"`
typeset -i x1_year=`date +"%Y"`
x1_datestring=`$x1_day_of_month $x1_month_of_year $x1_year`
x1_listofdates="
30Sep2019
if [ "$x1_D" = "$x1_$listofdates"] ; then
echo "Run job"
elseif [ $x1_FLAGRUN != 1 ] ; then
echo "do not run fancyjob today"
exit`

Comment: There is a more concise method that I have successfully *tested*:

https://serverfault.com/questions/55481/does-31-necessarily-imply-the-end-of-the-month-in-a-cron-job

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to do this with cron alone. You will have to run your application every day and have it decide if today is a the last working day of a month or not and take appropriate action.

Comment: please can you advise on how i should proceed. thanks.

Comment: My best advice is to use the on site search or your favourite search engine.,

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the syntax below:

`0 0 LW * ?`.

Comment: This does not work, did you check it ? If so, where ? We should always strive to give accurate and useful answers.